# change order form in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want  to change order form in OpenCart. Which file I change? How can I make this changes?

Comment: Order of what? items?  product order?

Comment: @user3176663, This is not a programming question and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the checkout page template files in:

`catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout` folder (if you're using 'default' theme, otherwise change `default` with your theme name.)